# Django Unknown column

Tags: django

I have a model with the following fields

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

  user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, db_index=True, 
  related_name='profile')
  Email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, db_index=True, null=True)
  name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, db_index=True)

class Meta(object):
    db_table = "auth_userprofile"
```

in my Users panel inside the Django Adminsitration i have multiple users, when i try to acces one of them i get this following error

> (1054, "Unknown column 'auth_userprofile.user_id' in 'field list'")

should i drop the table to fix this issue or there is another solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the table will require you to recreate it. And if you recreate it precisely as it is now, the issue will not be resolved.

This error:
(1054, "Unknown column 'auth_userprofile.user_id' in 'field list'")

Is refering to a specified column, very likely in a SQL statement, where you claiming a table, auth_userprofile, has the column: user_id.

Or it could be a syntax error, and you are including the table name in the column name section, or actually quite a lot of possible errors come to mind.

The point is deleting the table will only help if you re-create it with altered column names. 
And dropping an entire table to either alter a column name in your code, or simply creating the column in the table seems a bit excessive?

Comment: i changed the filed name from user to myuser (i don't know why i thought that will solvev the problem ) and i'm getting this **You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'myuser' to userprofile without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py**  i think i'm having that because of the existing rows in the table, should i delete all the rows (users) ?

Comment: No. deleting all data will not help. This issue is the modifcation you are trying to make doesn't have a default value, and you have set the column attribute "Is nullable" to no. Either it must be allowed to have a null value, or you need to supply a default value.

Comment: i added a default value to the field and run **migrations**  wich works fine but when i run **migrate**  i get this error **(1054, "Unknown column 'user_id' in 'auth_userprofile'")**

Comment: Ah thats because you didn't do the alteration via the migrate function. So now, when you try to do a migrate, it does not recognize the field.  (As there is no record of it in the migration histroy).

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: Remove your modification manually, and then let the migration tool do it? 
Or modify your migration history to artificially include the generation of the column?

Comment: thanks for your answers, it's now working, all i had to do is to edit the migration file manually